# Is there a possibility to add a time limit to <play>

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I would like to play the audio in the given url but is there a way to play it only for 30 seconds

Comment: Could you shorten the audio file to 30 seconds?

Comment: Process audio file and short it to 30 sec duration than loop only 1 time.